# Why would you use a constexpr on a constructor?

Tags: c++, constexpr

I understand that `constexpr` would allow you to be able to use an object as a constant at compile time, but what is an example of when this would be beneficial? I'm trying to understand the keyword better, but I can't find a good example that goes over when using it on a constructor that explains why it's needed.

Both of the examples below work, so then why is the constexpr placed on the constructor?

**With constexpr on constructor:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rect
{
    public:
        constexpr Rect(int width, int height)
            : mWidth(width), mHeight(height) {}
        constexpr int getArea() const { return mWidth * mHeight; }
    private:
        int mWidth, mHeight;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    constexpr Rect r(8, 2);

    cout << r.getArea() << endl;   //16

    int myArray[r.getArea()];    // OK


    return 0;
}
```

**Without constexpr on constructor:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Rect
{
    public:
        Rect(int width, int height)
            : mWidth(width), mHeight(height) {}
        constexpr int getArea() const { return mWidth * mHeight; }
    private:
        int mWidth, mHeight;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Rect r(8, 2);

    cout << r.getArea() << endl;   //16

    int myArray[r.getArea()];    // OK


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Second one doesn't compile for me: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a84bbdd8fb82bb49

Comment: But constexpr is placed on both examples for `getArea()`.

Comment: A function marked `constexpr` only returns a constant expression if its arguments (including implied `*this`) are also constant expressions

Comment: @Brian clang accepts the code. I started a [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489369/constexpr-member-function-with-non-constexpr-constructor-gcc-clang-differ) to seek help

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In your second example, `int myArray[r.getArea()];` is not permitted in Standard C++ because `r.getArea()` is not a constant expression.  (If your compiler accepts it then you are relying on a compiler extension, and should produce a warning if you invoke the compiler in conforming mode).

The difference might be more obvious if you change the array to:

```
std::array<int, r.getArea()> myArray;
```

which it is unlikely for the compiler to accept in the non-`constexpr` version.

Comment: Well that really doesn't address my question, but what you are basically saying is that you would only use `constexpr` on a constructor that would be producing an object that would be required to be used as a literal at compile time?

Comment: @EavenSheets You asked "Both of the examples below work, so then why is the constexpr placed on the constructor?" . I addressed this by showing that your second example actually does not work , and placing `constexpr` on the constructor makes it work.  "Why would you use a constexpr on a constructor?" is answered by "If you want objects of that class to be able to be used to generate a constant expression".

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I think it does. Perhaps you can post your own answer if you disagree