# constexpr non-static member function with non-constexpr constructor (gcc,clang differ)

Tags: c++, gcc, clang, c++14, constexpr

For this code:

```
struct S
{
    S(int m): m(m) {}
    constexpr int f() const { return m; }

    int m;
};

int main() { S s(1); }
```

it is compiled with no warnings or errors by clang 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8 with `-std=c++14`.  But in g++ 5.x the following errors occur:

```
main.cpp:4:19: error: enclosing class of constexpr non-static member function 'int S::f() const' is not a literal type
     constexpr int f() const { return m; }
               ^
main.cpp:1:8: note: 'S' is not literal because:
 struct S
        ^
main.cpp:1:8: note:   'S' is not an aggregate, does not have a trivial default constructor, and has no constexpr constructor that is not a copy or move constructor
```

Which compiler is correct and why?

I looked at the requirements in C++14 [dcl.constexpr]/3 which says that for a `constexpr` function "each of its parameter types shall be a literal type",  but that section does not explicitly mention member functions, and does not say whether the implied `*this` counts as a parameter for the purposes of this clause.

Comment: I doubt that such a member function could be actually useful, because it definitely can't be calculated in compile-time, isn't it? So I would say, gcc diagnostics is more correct.

Comment: To make sure I just tried a trunk GCC build and it's still broken.

Comment: @user657267 OK.  Perhaps it's not a high priority; as user3159253 points out, this code is not very useful because the evaluation of `f()` will actually be non-constexpr, even in clang, because `S` is not a literal type (so `constexpr S s(1);` is not allowed).

Comment: @M.M I can see only one use case to allow constexpr on non-static member function of non-literal type. It's generic code when template class can be literal or non-literal depending on template parameters.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a core defect that was fixed for C++14

http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_defects.html#1684

Clang was patched

https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/#!topic/std-discussion/6jM8M8FUs30

There's a tracker for GCC but it doesn't look like anyone has addressed it yet

https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66297

Comment: Isn't this applied only to _static_ member functions?

Comment: The comments on the DR suggest that the previous behaviour was intended for non-static member and this change was intended to fix static member... but the actual change appears to apply to both. The plot thickens?

Comment: In fact the mailing list link explains that the committee decided to remove it intentionally for non-static too, in a change from what the DR originally recommended

Comment: @user3159253 Well the DR comment only mentions static functions but the wording of the fix applies to non-static functions too, as M.M mentions this was ultimately intended, ironically it looks like the DR might have introduced another defect itself if they hadn't.

Comment: For info: this was fixed in gcc 7.2, approx August 2017 (see https://gcc.gnu.org/viewcvs/gcc?view=revision&revision=248752)

Comment: @Matthias I'm not an expert on this but AFAICS all the discussion refers to C++14 (and later), not C++11. user657267 presumably would be able to say for definite.