# C++ how can I read runtime bitset parameter from file which I will use non-constexpr class

Tags: c++, c++11, constexpr, compile-time, bitset

I have a problem and can not figure it out on my own. I am describing it and want you to give me ideas about it, please.

I need to define a bitset with dynamic size:

```
int x = fileparser.read("value"); // This fileparser is a custom class that reads .ini files.
std::bitset<x> myBitset;
```

but this bitset's size should be read from the file. So as you know, bitset **can not handle** **runtime parameters** cause of template arguments.

- I wrote a file parser class but I can not convert it to **constexpr** because it is a singleton and should return a static instance in one of its methods.
- I don't want to use the **boost library**.
- Also C++11 has a defect in constexpr classes and I'm facing it (ref: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36489493/12347681)

So, how can I handle it? I want to read a value from the file and use it as a constexpr.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**: When I convert my reader class to constexpr, I am facing the above defect from C++11. Is there a way to use my file reader class to determine the size of the bitset?

Comment: do you know the maximum value of `x` ? Use that instead of `x`

Comment: C++ does not work this way. A `constexpr` value must be known at compile-time because, well, that's what it is by definition. "[Reading] a value from the file and use it as a constexpr" will require figuring out a way to violate fundamental laws of physics of our shared universe in order to produce a compile-time constant from some data that's only known at runtime.

Comment: Don't use `std::bitset`, replace it with a vector of unsigned numbers. And I'm unsure what the linked defect has to do with it.

Comment: No, I don't know the max value of it because everytime I run the program it can be change by the config file. @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: then you cannot use `std::bitset`. As already stated, you'd need to invent time travel to make a number read from a file during runtime known at compile time.

Comment: I want to use std::bitset, it has a lot of benefits for my program.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, linked defect which I am facing with my code when I try to convert it to constexpr.

Comment: I hate to say it, but have you've heard of [`std::vector<bool>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector_bool)

Comment: `std::bitset` has fixed size, you want size to be dynamic, ergo you do not want `std::bitset`. I mean you can wish things to be different but they arent. You write already " So as you know, bitset can not handle runtime parameters cause of template arguments." regarding `std::bitset` there isnt much to add

Comment: *I don't want to use the boost library.* -- But nothing stops you from looking at the library to see how to implement such a class.  It's only C++ code, albeit well-tuned.

Comment: you said you want `x` to be different on different runs of the program (implies: without recompiling), hence the issue with getting `x` at compile time is not the defect you link (to see its relevance a [mcve] would be required) nor any technical issue, but the mere fact that you only know the size at runtime

Comment: The defect that I linked to this issue is not about the x value nor determining x in runtime. It is about the convert my filereader class to constexpr. When I convert it to constexpr, I'm facing a defect that I linked. @463035818_is_not_a_number

Comment: As the saying goes, you're trying to squeeze blood out of a stone.  The defect was fixed in C++14.  Have you tried compiling your code in C++14 to see if it was fixed?

Comment: that defect can be workedaround I suppose, but you cannot work around a value read at runtime not being known at compile time.

Comment: I have a lot of dependencies on C++11. (Such as third party packages) Did not try because did not dare. @PaulMcKenzie

Comment: Why not use the type that is returned by `fileparser.read("value")`?

Comment: Please explain for what this `std::bitset` is used why it needs to have dynamic size? Which operations of bitset are important? Note that currently I suspect [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/). To answer this questions please [edit] your question instead posting more comments, so anyone who sees it for the first time do not have to go through all comments to have full picture of a problem.

Comment: What about splitting your program in two parts? The first one that parse the file and extract the `x` value, then call a makefile and make the second program (where the value of `x` is a define) with the bitset.