# Is it necessary to instantiate constexpr constructor of a class into a constexpr object?

Tags: c++, constexpr

I have some misunderstandings regarding constexpr and trying to learn it by example. I have a class which has constexpr constructor:

```
class Shape{
public:
    constexpr Shape(int x, int y, int z) : 
       m_x(x), m_y(y), m_z(z)
    {}
```

Do I need to use a constexpr object always when instantiating for this to be considered compile-time:
What is the difference between:

```
constexpr Shape s{10,20,20};
```

and

```
Shape s{10,20,20};
```

Google search didn't help me much. I apologize if the question is missing any required information. I can provide if requested. Thanks.

Comment: The first one is `constexpr` while the second one is not. Meaning **the first one can be used in `constexpr` context.** while the second one cannot be used in such a context.

Comment: Related/dupe: [Does specifying constexpr on a constructor automatically make all objects created from it to be constexpr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31375381/does-specifying-constexpr-on-a-constructor-automatically-make-all-objects-create) and [Why would you use a constexpr on a constructor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36489123/why-would-you-use-a-constexpr-on-a-constructor)

Comment: If I used the first one, then the functions I use on it should be const (not modifying attributes), is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is one implication of `constexpr` as it means top level const also. Also, it(`constexpr` on a ctor) is similar to `constexpr` applied on a ordinary function.

Comment: `constexpr` on a function means it can be called at compile time, not that it must be called at compile time. Its not different on the constructor. Also `constexpr` on a declaration implies `const`. `Shape s{10,20,20};` is not `const`, it would be weird if it was

Comment: [It is possible that a function declared as constexpr can be called during run-time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14248235/when-does-a-constexpr-function-get-evaluated-at-compile-time)

Comment: Great, Okay so in this case, if I use constexpr constructor, but declare it not as constexpr, it makes sense because I will eventually have to do some changes in the Shape attributes.

Comment: Guys, thank you for answers. I noticed that this is duplicate, so do what you gotta do to mark it as duplicate please.